# libGDX: one actor on another input

Tags: libgdx, listener, actor

I'm writing checkers and have two types of actors: checkers and squares. And have a listener that react if the square was touched. But this works only if the square is empty. If checker is placed on top I can't do anything. If there smth like "priority" of actor(?) or a method that could help?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Touches are processed in the opposite order that they are added to the Group. This is also the reverse of the order they are drawn, so if something is drawn on top of something, it will also have touch priority over what is behind it.

In this case, it sounds like you need to set all your checkers to not be touchable. `actor.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled)`